# Getting "make: Entering an unknown directory" error while building postgresql in a subsystem

Tags: linux, postgresql, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to install postgresql on MIPS platform and I am getting the following error while building it.

```
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/shreesha/platform/utils/postgresql-9.3.4/src/port'
/home/shreesha/platform/tools/bin/make -C timezone all
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/shreesha/platform/utils/postgresql-9.3.4/src/timezone'

/home/shreesha/platform/tools/bin/make -C common all

**make: Entering an unknown directory**

make: *** common: No such file or directory.  Stop.

make: Leaving an unknown directory

make[4]: *** [common-recursive] Error 2

make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/shreesha/platform/utils/postgresql-9.3.4/src/timezone'
make[3]: *** [all-timezone-recurse] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/shreesha/platform/utils/postgresql-9.3.4/src'
make[2]: *** [all-src-recurse] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shreesha/platform/utils/postgresql-9.3.4'
```

Do we need to set any specific make variables/environmental variables in this case?
Any help on debugging this is much appreciated!

Comment: `make --version`? `configure` version? How did you get the Pg sources - from git, from a tarball download, ... ?

Comment: it seems postgresql-9.3.4 package is not proper from where you have download it??

Comment: @Craig:bash-4.1$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
bash-4.1$

Comment: @Rahul: I downloaded this from http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.3.4/ The package is installing fine in x86 platform(which infers that the package is proper). When I am trying to install in mips platform, I am getting this error. I searched many links looking for this issue but still couldn't find any good solutions for this problem.

Comment: I don't think we have MIPS in our buildfarm  (http://buildfarm.postgresql.org/) so it might well not work without changes - a new `port/` file for locking assembler, etc, for example. It might be a good idea to post to pgsql-hackers with this report. Include a link to this question, and please comment here when you've posted.

Comment: Can you provide compilation steps for MIPS platform??

Comment: @ALL: I have posted the question in pgsql-hackers. Following is the link: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Getting-make-Entering-an-unknown-directory-error-while-building-postgresql-on-MIPS-platform-td5806705.html

Comment: @RahulRDhobi: I have started the configure with the following options:'--target=mips-linux-gnu' '--host=mips-linux-gnu' '--without-readline' '--without-zlib' '--prefix=/home/shreesha/platform/tools/porfidio_obj' 'host_alias=mips-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=mips-linux-gnu' 'CC=/home/shreesha/db_porting/build/srao_sc_client/Default/porfidio/tools/mipscross-xlp/linux/bin/mips64-nlm-linux-gcc -B/home/shreesha/db_porting/build/srao_sc_client/Default/porfidio/tools/mipscross-xlp/linux -B/home/shreesha/platform/tools/mipscross-xlp/linux/lib ' 'LDFLAGS= -mabi=32 -march=xlp'

Comment: 'CPP=/home/shreesha/platform/tools/mipscross-xlp/linux/bin/mips64-nlm-linux-cpp'